# Subgroups of the group of automorphisms of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Let $G$ denote the group of all automorphisms of the field $F_{3^{100}}$. Then, what is the number of distinct subgroups of $G$?

First of all I have to compute $G$. Now 
\begin{equation*}
F_{3^{100}}(+) \cong Z/3Z \times Z/3Z \times Z/3Z\times....Z/3Z
\end{equation*}
($100$ times). Now what do I do compute the possible group automorphisms first?

Should I look at the basis elements $(1,0,0,0,0,....0),(0,1,0,0,0.....0)...$ and where I send them to would determine all automorphisms? or am I wrong?

Comment: You seem to be counting the automorphisms of your big field *as finite group*. But you need to look at field automorphisms, which are far fewer in number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the automorphism group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\phi$ defined where $a \mapsto a^p$.  In particular, this implies that the automorphism group is cyclic (and ultimately of order $n$).

One way of going about showing this is by first proving that finite extensions of finite fields are Galois, then recalling that, for any Galois extension $K$ of a base field $F$, we have $| \operatorname{Aut}(K/F) | = [K:F]$.  In this case,  $K = \mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ and $F = \mathbb{F}_p$, and $[K:F] = n$.  So it suffices to show that $\operatorname{id}, \phi, \phi^2, \phi^3, ..., \phi^{n-1}$ are all unique automorphisms, and since there are $n$ of them, the list must be exhaustive.  To show these are unique automorphisms and none wrap back around to the identity for any $0 \leq k < n$, note that $\phi^k$ maps $a \mapsto a^{p^k}$, and then consider the polynomial $x^{p^k} - x$; you can arrive at a contradiction via a degree of the polynomial / number of roots argument.

At any rate, the first paragraph implies that $\displaystyle \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_{3^{100}}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/100\mathbb{Z}$.  Now counting the number of subgroups is much easier!

---

For further reading, see this document by Keith Conrad: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/math5211s13/handouts/finitefield.pdf